# Method for checking if point is inside triangle doesn't work in three-dimensional space

Tags: geometry

I'm using a method presented on this page http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html, to calculate if given point lies inside a triangle. All images in this post are borrowed from this page.

Say we want to check if point P lies inside triangle consisting of points V0, V1 and V2.

The parametric equation of a plane is:

[image]

If s and t are greater or equal to zero and s+t is less or equal to 1, then the point lies inside the triangle.

Say u = V1-V0, v = V2-V0 and w = P-V0. Then we calculate s and t like this:

[image]

[image]

However this seems to only be valid in two-dimensional space. Say we create a triangle consisting of points: (x=0, y=0, z=0), (x=2, y=0, z=0), (x=1, y=0, z=2). If point P is at (x=1, y=0, z=1) it's considered to be inside the triangle. However if we change the y coordinate of point P to any non-zero value, with this method, it is still considered to be inside the triangle.

Can we extend this method for three-dimensional space?

Comment: You also want to ensure that the point lies on the plane of the triangle. Use the normal vector of the plane for that.

Comment: @CalvinLin How do I check if the point lies on the plane using its normal vector?

Comment: The projection v_1 onto another vector v_2 gives the minimal distance between the origin and the plane that is perpendicular to v_2 and passes through v_1.

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm sorry I don't understand this explanation. Am I correct to assume that if the dot product of the normal and direction vector (P-V0) is zero, than the point P lies on the plane?

Comment: Yes! That works.

Comment: @CalvinLin Awesome, thanks!